# Pressing keys by python not working at all(win7)

Tags: python, windows-7

I tried using WScript.Shell and
`shell.SendKeys('w')`, tried using `pyautogui.KeyDown/KeyUp` or just win32 features, but none of them pressing anything. I had the same problem on win10, but I fixed it somehow, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By the way, it is working using `win32api.keybd_event()` directly, but let me now if you know, why win32 shell and pyautogui is not.